# RUN mkdir folder, ADD folder/ . and COPY folder/ . in Dockerfile are not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose, solr

I've been trying to build the service solr in docker, have written a Dockerfile to build a image, what's in Dockerfile is below.

```
FROM solr:8.6.3
LABEL maintainer="halloweens"

# create Core
USER root
WORKDIR /opt/solr-8.6.3/server/solr  
# RUN mkdir ik_core  // didn't work, so I annotated
ADD ik_core/ .      // I was trying this way to add this directory into it, COPY as well, didn't work 
WORKDIR ik_core
RUN echo 'name=ik_core' > core.properties
# RUN mkdir data    // didn't work, so I annotated

# setup the ik-analyzer    // this part quite succeeded
WORKDIR /opt/solr-8.6.3/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
ADD ik-analyzer-8.3.0.jar .
ADD solr-core-8.6.3.jar .
ADD solr-dataimporthandler-8.6.3.jar .
ADD solr-dataimporthandler-extras-8.6.3.jar .
ADD solr-solrj-8.6.3.jar .
WORKDIR /opt/solr-8.6.3/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF
ADD hotword.dic .
ADD stopword.dic .
ADD IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml .

# add conf
ADD managed-schema /opt/solr-8.6.3/server/solr/ik_core/conf  // oop, it's like doesn't have the targer directory, so, didn't work

USER solr

WORKDIR /opt/solr-8.6.3
```

the mainly problems are it cannot new folder in it and it cannot move/copy folder into it as well, here are some messages while building this image.

```
Building solr
Step 1/20 : FROM solr:8.6.3
 ---> 6cd44b0427c6
Step 2/20 : LABEL maintainer="halloweens"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c00102273187
Step 3/20 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf673ba7db76
Step 4/20 : WORKDIR /opt/solr-8.6.3/server/solr
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 49944dc42904
Step 5/20 : ADD ik_core/ .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a1242656d9b6
Step 6/20 : WORKDIR ik_core
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3324f309b66d
Step 7/20 : RUN echo 'name=ik_core' > core.properties
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 93375111a380
Step 8/20 : WORKDIR /opt/solr-8.6.3/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 090df62ab5f9
Step 9/20 : ADD ik-analyzer-8.3.0.jar .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 151144e7e5b2
Step 10/20 : ADD solr-core-8.6.3.jar .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5b12febb071c
Step 11/20 : ADD solr-dataimporthandler-8.6.3.jar .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d738b7026a4e
Step 12/20 : ADD solr-dataimporthandler-extras-8.6.3.jar .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> aa2d0a16524d
Step 13/20 : ADD solr-solrj-8.6.3.jar .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 10562eab8c4b
Step 14/20 : WORKDIR /opt/solr-8.6.3/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ce0c98054b6e
Step 15/20 : ADD hotword.dic .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> de3ad2605a45
Step 16/20 : ADD stopword.dic .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c25cc36a0513
Step 17/20 : ADD IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e1c19c123f2c
Step 18/20 : ADD managed-schema /opt/solr-8.6.3/server/solr/ik_core/conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f8d6d2dd9ed6
Step 19/20 : USER solr
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 989221e33b98
Step 20/20 : WORKDIR /opt/solr-8.6.3
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5d6c68254e72
Successfully built 5d6c68254e72
Successfully tagged solr_solr:latest
Creating solr ... done
```

the owner and the group is the same.

```
total 18308
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root           937 Jul 17 13:31 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 halloweens halloweens       6 Oct 28  2020 hotword.dic
-rw-r--r-- 1 halloweens halloweens 9686058 Oct 22  2020 ik-analyzer-8.3.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 halloweens halloweens     589 Oct 28  2020 IKAnalyzer.cfg.xml
drwxr-xr-x 4 halloweens halloweens      30 Jul 17 13:18 ik_core
-rw-r--r-- 1 halloweens halloweens   64795 Nov  5  2020 managed-schema
-rw-r--r-- 1 halloweens halloweens 6369473 Oct  3  2020 solr-core-8.6.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 halloweens halloweens  231329 Oct  3  2020 solr-dataimporthandler-8.6.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 halloweens halloweens   41007 Oct  3  2020 solr-dataimporthandler-extras-8.6.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 halloweens halloweens   11858 Jul 17 12:05 solr.in.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 halloweens halloweens 2311259 Oct  3  2020 solr-solrj-8.6.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 halloweens halloweens       8 Oct 28  2020 stopword.dic
```

below is what in the ik_core folder.

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 halloweens halloweens 6 Jul 17 13:18 conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 halloweens halloweens 6 Jul 17 13:13 data
```

Comment: The build log you show says the image built successfully; what's the problem you're running into?  It looks like you're building this via Compose, are the contents of the `docker-compose.yml` necessary to reproduce the issue?  (If you look at the [base `solr` image Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr/blob/0a9474015d0fe6dd9e29388a0f733f2ef1848523/8.6/Dockerfile), it installs into `/opt/solr/server` without including the version number in the directory name, which could potentially be connected to your issue?)

Comment: It did build successfully, the problem is some commands in the Dockerfile didn't execute/work, RUN mkdir folder, ADD folder/  .  and COPY folder/  .  these three, like I said,  it cannot create folder in it and it cannot move/copy folder into it as well, but single file is fine, that's what got me confused, hope I make some sence here@DavidMaze